# Configuring domain to direct email and web traffic to different IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, email, alias, redirection, mx-record

I'm totally fine with setting up sub-domains etc when managing my domain but I've recently been asked to direct all mail for a domain to a particular exchange so people can retrieve email for the domain using their normal email addresses (on a different domain) and I'm slightly embarrassed to admit that I'm not really sure what to do.

The situation I'm trying to get to is:

*Website is at: www.mydomain.com*

*Any mail through the site sent to e.g. info@mydomain.com, john@mydomain.com needs to be sent to info@theirdomain.com and john@theirdomain.com.*

Now, from my limited understanding of the way email works in DNS my reckoning is that I can set up an MX record that points to the IP of their mail exchange.  Then they can set up aliases to check for info@mydomain.com and direct it to info@theirdomain.com.  Is this correct?

If so, how do I set it up?  If not, what do I need to do to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, on mydomain.com's dns servers setup A records pointing to their mail servers as well MX records specifying those A names.

Comment: Cheers, so do you mean I should set up an A record with, say, mail.mydomain.com which points to their exchange server's IP address and then set mydomain.com's MX record to point to mail.mydomain.com?

Comment: @fat_tony yeppers

Comment: Thanks.  Marking this answer as accepted as this was the first answer and did the trick.  I will, however, vote up both answers (just as soon as I have enough rep!) as both are helpful.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways to achieve this, but assuming that you control only the DNS server, you are on the right track:

- Configure the DNS zone so that [the      MX points to the correct name](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/mx.html) of     the Exchange server (not the IP       address)
- Have the Exchange server admins deal    with accepting email for the domain    and the required mapping between the    old and the new domains that are to    be handled by Exchange